# Why ActiveRecord Model.import is failing to insert bulk records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, bulk-load

I am trying to insert about 200,000 records using ActiveRecord import method. It's failing with **TypeError: can't quote Hash** error. I searched in the net, but nothing meaningful related to my scenario.

I started with smaller size and was successful up to  120,000 records. If I keep trying I think I can find a limit. Is there anything else I can do other than inserting the records into smaller batch?

Here is my configuration - Rails 5.0.3, Ruby 2.3.0, Mysql 5.1.73. I know these are very outdated.

Anyone had similar issue and how did you fix it?

Comment: Oh I just saw that ver 5 MySQL .. im not sure but I can't help but feel like if you upgrade to 8, you might not have the problem if its not a validation issue.

Comment: Hmm smaller batches don't error out?  I wonder if its a connection timeout issue?  Perhaps its set low enough that the batch takes longer than the timeout and it errors, so on smaller runs its fine?

Comment: @easleyfixed can you suggest if I can try something to check if its a validation issue. Are you referring to the Rails import options?  Where can I check for the connection timeout?  Yes smaller batch working fine.

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure about the Rails end of it, and AFAIK I don't think MySQL cares too much about # but it does about ' and / and a few other things that cause issues if not terminated.  The MySQL connection timeout is set within MySQL.  An easier way to do that is use MySQL Workbench so you can get in there and poke around in a GUI instead of a CLI.

Comment: Also I wonder what your bulk insert size is ? Increase bulk_insert_buffer_size to a higher value.  Also your read_buffer might need to be larger, maybe even key_buffer_size increase.  And MAYBE it needs to clear after transaction commit with innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit needing to be set to 2.  These are stabs in the dark of course, but hopefully get you onto the right path.

Comment: If there isn't an explicit requirement that this be done with Ruby, you could use the included `mysqlimport` command that is often used for this.

Comment: It is failing in a single line of code: `Model.import  columns, values`
values is an Array of records filled as 
`values << [val1, val2, val3, val4, ...val12]`

Comment: @engineersmnky you pointed to the right direction. So, some of the hash was empty and in the values there were {} . So, some values in the insert record were like [{val, val,val} , {val, {},val} ]. If you can move your comment in the answer section, then I can accept this as correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"TypeError: can't quote Hash" is thrown by the connection adapter. [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L29).

This error can be easily recreated:

```
Arel::Nodes.build_quoted({}).to_sql. 
#=> TypeError: can't quote Hash
```

This means that it is likely that somewhere in the records you are trying to import there is a bare Hash, rather than JSON (which is probably what was intended).

If this is the case you may need to search through the records to determine where these offending Hashes are and modify them accordingly. For instance if they are intended to be JSON data you can use `Hash#to_json` to convert them.